# В slick slider добавлять класс при событии draggable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Подскажите как реализовать чтобы при событии в слайдере draggable нужному блоку work-links добавлялся класс active, а сотальным удалялся, чтобы не как костыль был, а при любой смене слайдера менялись и соответствующие блоки, тоесть подкрашивались желтым цветом

```js
$('.our-work-slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  arrows: true,
  draggable: true,
  fade: true
});

$('.work-link-item').click(function() {
  $('.work-link-item').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.our-work-slider').slick('slickGoTo', $(this).index());
});
```

```html
<div class="how-we-work-wrapper">
  <div class="page-container">
    <div class="how-we-work-header">
      <div class="how-we-work-left">
        <div class="we-work-title">
          Как мы работаем?
        </div>
        <div class="we-work-subtitle">
          За годы работы мы выработали оптимальный<br> вариант сотрудничества с заказчиком.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="how-we-work-right">
        <div class="small-btn modal-open order-link">
          Узнать подробнее об оплате
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="we-work-container-dots">
      <div class="work-links justify-wrap">
        <div class="work-link-item active" aria-controls="slick-slide00">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                     Оплата
                 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="work-link-item" aria-controls="slick-slide00">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                     Анализ
                 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="work-link-item" aria-controls="slick-slide01">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                     Стратегия
                 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="work-link-item" aria-controls="slick-slide02">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                     Разработка
                 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="work-link-item" aria-controls="slick-slide03">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                     Реклама
                 </a>
        </div>
        <span class="empty-span"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="our-work-slider">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="our-work-row-item">
          <div class="our-work-row__left">
            <div class="our-work-row__content">
              <div class="our-work-content__title">
                У нас есть два варианта сотрудничества1
              </div>
              <div class="our-work-content__text">
                <p>
                  <span>А —</span> Мы работаем с Вами по классической схеме 30% предоплата до начала работ - 70% пост-оплата после утверждения дизайн-макета.
                </p>
                <p>
                  <span>Б —</span> Вы получаете индивидуальную скидку при полной предоплате.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="our-work-row__right">
            <img src="images/w-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="our-work-row-item">
          <div class="our-work-row__left">
            <div class="our-work-row__content">
              <div class="our-work-content__title">
                У нас есть два варианта сотрудничества2
              </div>
              <div class="our-work-content__text">
                <p>
                  <span>А —</span> Мы работаем с Вами по классической схеме 30% предоплата до начала работ - 70% пост-оплата после утверждения дизайн-макета.
                </p>
                <p>
                  <span>Б —</span> Вы получаете индивидуальную скидку при полной предоплате.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="our-work-row__right">
            <img src="images/w-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="our-work-row-item">
          <div class="our-work-row__left">
            <div class="our-work-row__content">
              <div class="our-work-content__title">
                У нас есть два варианта сотрудничества3
              </div>
              <div class="our-work-content__text">
                <p>
                  <span>А —</span> Мы работаем с Вами по классической схеме 30% предоплата до начала работ - 70% пост-оплата после утверждения дизайн-макета.
                </p>
                <p>
                  <span>Б —</span> Вы получаете индивидуальную скидку при полной предоплате.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="our-work-row__right">
            <img src="images/w-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="our-work-row-item">
          <div class="our-work-row__left">
            <div class="our-work-row__content">
              <div class="our-work-content__title">
                У нас есть два варианта сотрудничества4
              </div>
              <div class="our-work-content__text">
                <p>
                  <span>А —</span> Мы работаем с Вами по классической схеме 30% предоплата до начала работ - 70% пост-оплата после утверждения дизайн-макета.
                </p>
                <p>
                  <span>Б —</span> Вы получаете индивидуальную скидку при полной предоплате.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="our-work-row__right">
            <img src="images/w-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="our-work-row-item">
          <div class="our-work-row__left">
            <div class="our-work-row__content">
              <div class="our-work-content__title">
                У нас есть два варианта сотрудничества5
              </div>
              <div class="our-work-content__text">
                <p>
                  <span>А —</span> Мы работаем с Вами по классической схеме 30% предоплата до начала работ - 70% пост-оплата после утверждения дизайн-макета.
                </p>
                <p>
                  <span>Б —</span> Вы получаете индивидуальную скидку при полной предоплате.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="our-work-row__right">
            <img src="images/w-1.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать событие

> swipe

`$('.your-element').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
  $('#elem').addClass('active');
});`